# How to convert duplicate files into shortcuts to save space?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, shortcuts

I found out my C drive contains many duplicate files that consume space.  I don't want to delete them because it's risky and recovering them is hard.  Can I convert them all into shortcuts referencing one original file, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the files are *exact* duplicates (not just files with the same name), you *might* be able to delete all but one and make shortcuts, but even then, some programs might not work with a .lnk (shortcut file) to a DLL, for example. You'd need to test each link.

Better might be to find other items taking up space, such as backups of system files that Windows Update creates. Try this to delete unneeded files automatically:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cle` and select `cleanmgr.exe`.
- At the bottom of the dialog, click `Clean up system files`, and wait for the dialog to reappear.
- Select items to delete, confirm deletion, and *wait*. After an update, Windows may need to delete 4 GB or more.

**N.B.** After deleting old system files, you will be unable to back out of updates, so be sure your system is working before deleting the backups.

Comment: Using a Symbolic link or Junction might solve programs not working with shortcuts